# How can I transform a List<A> into List<B>?

Tags: java, list, guava

If A is defined like this:

```
class A {
    List<B> bList;
}
```

If a List of A's is given (List aList), how can I transform it into a List containing all the B's that are stored in each element from aList?
I would want to use guava to do this.

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: Best done with a few lines of code.

Comment: By running a `reduce function`. pseudocode: `a[].reduce = func(r, a) { return r + a.b }, []`

Comment: Such a simple task you should really have a go yourself first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should make it.

```
ImmutableList<B> listOfBs = FluentIterable.from(listOfAs)
  .transformAndConcat(new Function<A, List<B>>(){
      public List<B> apply(A a) {
        return a.bList;
      }
   })
   .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8 Solution

I know you want a Guava solution, but here is a Java 8 version for anyone interested.

Create a stream to Map `A.bList` for each `A` item to feed into the mapping function.

```
List<B> bList = aList.stream().map(a -> a.bList).flatMap(b -> b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

### Notes

Here is a similar example of `flatMap`: [Java 8 flatMap Example](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/java_8_flatmap_example).

Also, you can check out:

- [Rosetta Code: Flatten a list](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list#Java)
- [Wikipedia: Fold (higher-order function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29).